# Full page horizontal javascript accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I'm making a fairly simple on page javascript application. While it's one page, I'd like to have several pages of data. I'd like to have the entire page be a giant horizontal accordion. Clicking on the headers on either side would switch to the requisite page. I'd like to to fill the entire page so it doesn't leave empty space. Does anybody know of such a javascript library?

Thanks for your time.

Edit: I could set the width and height of a normal accordion library from the size of the window at page-load, but that doesn't adapt to page resizing very well (at all.).

Answer (score 1):

Check out [iridium.com](http://iridium.com/default.aspx), a site I worked on a while back. It's using a jQuery plug-in called "slide deck" which may suit your needs. You'd have to style it for full-page of course.

Comment: Slidedeck not only costs money (they include a free version) but doesn't let you set the width and height during configuration (afaict, from their documentation.) They offer no features on the variety of other accordion libraries I've found, and I'd like to keep the project as open source as possible.

Answer (score 1):

To readjust the main div per window resize:

```
window.onresize = function(event) { /* adjust fullscreen div here */ }
```

I recently worked on a fairly similar project for my personal portfolio - much like typical accordions but to prevent user confusion from the extra-tall accordion bits, the window scrolled as the giant accordion opened. check my profile if you care to take a gander